# defaultAnnotations Prop only working when I hard-code the data - React Annotation Tool

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm making a web-app which utilizes the [React Annotation Tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-annotation-tool).
I'm storing the drawn data in a mongoDB database, the schema of which is:

```
const VideoSchema = new Schema({
  drawnData: {
    type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    required: true,
  },
})
```

I've tried passing the saved data onto the defaultAnnotation prop, but it doesn't show the drawn rectangles; however, if I hard code the data, and pass it as that, the video shows the drawn data perfectly as shown:

```js
let oo = [ // hard coding the data
      {
        color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
        incidents: [
          {
            x: 184.25,
            y: 80,
            width: 99,
            height: 105,
            time: 0,
            status: "Show",
            id: "kacb6zeg",
            name: "kacb6zeg",
            label: "",
          },
        ],
        childrenNames: [],
        parentName: "",
        id: "kacb6zeg",
        name: "kacb6zeg",
        label: "1",
      },
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Main Implementation</h1>
        <TwoDimensionalVideo // this implementation works
          url={video}
          defaultAnnotations={oo}
          onSubmit={(e) => this.submit(e)}
        />
        <TwoDimensionalVideo // this does not work
          url={video}
          defaultAnnotations={
            this.state.ready ? this.state.defaultAnnotations : []
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
```

This is how I'm storing data in the state object:

```js
    const response = await fetch("/getData");
    const json = await response.json();

    this.setState({ defaultData: json.data[0].drawnData.data }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.defaultData[0]);
      this.defaultAnnotations = this.state.defaultData[0];
      this.setState({
        defaultAnnotations: this.defaultAnnotations,
        ready: true,
      });
    });
```

And this is how I'm inserting data into the database:

```
submit(e) {
    this.filterData(e);
  }

  filterData(data) {
    this.insertVideoData(data.annotations);
  }

  async insertVideoData(data) {
    // console.log(data);
    this.options.body = JSON.stringify({ data });

    const response = await fetch("/insertData", this.options);
    const res = await response.json();

    if (res.message !== "Not Inserted") {
      alert("Data Inserted");
    } else {
      alert("some problem");
      console.log(res);
    }
  }
```

The hard coded data is taken directly from my database, and is how it appears if I console.log it. This may prove that the data structure isn't the problem.

### Could someone please point me in the right direction? Also, I'm new to react, so please forgive the trash code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the problem. I was creating an object of data when I was inserting it through my API. So I changed

> this.options.body = JSON.stringify({ data });

to

> this.options.body = JSON.stringify(data);

I also modified the way I was rendering the component, so I changed

```js
<TwoDimensionalVideo // this does not work
          url={video}
          defaultAnnotations={
          this.state.ready ? this.state.defaultAnnotations : []
        }
     />
```

to

```js
{this.state.tag}
```

and changed the state object to

```js
this.setState({
    tag: (
            <TwoDimensionalVideo
            url={video}
            onSubmit={(e) => {this.submit(e)}
            defaultAnnotations={json.data[0].drawnData}}
            />
        ),
})
```

in the componentDidMount function